# chrome remote interface with nodejs fails with ReferenceError

Tags: node.js, automation, google-chrome-devtools

I try to use the remote interface of chrome to navigate to an webpage.
Why does the following  example code fail?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var cri = require('chrome-remote-interface');
console.error(cri);

cri(function(chrome) {
        with (chrome) {
                on('Network.requestWillBeSent', function(message) {
                        console.log(message.request.url);
                });
                on('Package.loadEventFired', close);
                Network.enable();
                Page.enable();
                Page.navigate({'uri': 'https://github.com'});
        }
}).on('error', function () {
  console.error('Cannot connect to Chrome');
});
```

It fails with:

```
{ [Function] createClient: [Function] }
/home/test/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/index.js:36
                    chrome.connectToWebSocket.call(self, tabDebuggerUrl);
                                                   ^

ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `Package.loadEventFired`, Use `Page.loadEventFired`. It should solve the issue.